# What is the name of this two player card game for betting?

Tags: identify-this-game, two-player, betting

There is a two-player game in Sri Lanka using the French card deck. One of the players shuffles the deck and the second player bets for a card value (without the suit).

If the requested card value comes next in the deck, the better wins, if not, he loses.

Does someone know the name of this game?

Comment: How many cards are drawn?  Is this just a guessing game without any strategy?

Comment: Sounds  like a simple guessing game using a deck of cards and not an actual game that would have an official name.

Comment: there's no strategy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to actually be a card game and the details for rules are unspecified.

Comment: I don't think trivial games are off-topic - War and Candyland are also 100% luck yet they have multiple questions each on this site.

Comment: And it's quite standard for identify-this-game questions to be somewhat shaky on the details - that's often why they need our help identifying it. Though @OP if you know anything else about the game, including its name in another language, please tell us.

Comment: As of current, it's a bit too vague and lack of details, though you can always [edit] your question to add more details and getting focused answers instead of wild guessing the name of the game. If possible, could you show either/both an example of how the game progresses, or otherwise answers these questions: how many tries/turns does the player have? how many cards are drawn per turn? if multiple turns, are they discarded/returned back to the deck after being drawn?

Comment: @Ryanyuyu: It is a vaguely-posed question but it is 100% on topic

Comment: @Laska I'd argue it's too vague and underspecified. How many cards are drawn?  What does "comes next in the deck" mean?  Is the payout even money?   As it stands, we currently have two answers that are "I don't think this is what you're talking about, but I found a game from Sri Lanka".  I still think it's too unclear.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.pagat.com/national/sri_lanka.html lists numerous card games but none of those which are explained match OP’s details. Still the name might ring a bell

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  For example, you should include the names of the games you think could be what the question is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about two-player games, but there's a game 304 and Omi that are similar to what you've described.

Comment: Both of those games are complex trick-taking games with more than two players.  This answer is likely incorrect.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Since the original post had wrong grammar I search for games based on their region - Sri Lanka - and those two games were the only two card games I found.

Comment: But neither of their rules seem to match the question.  While these games do appear to be Sri Lankan, they don't match the simple "guess the card" rule.

Comment: @ryanyuyu And these appear to be the only card games in Sri Lanka.